# DocuSign branding with Demo Integrator Key

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on a solution for a customer that uses the DocuSign API from C#.
Currently the project has not passed the "Final OK" from the customer and is still in the demo phase.
The customer wants the DocuSign emails to be branded.
It seems, however, that the Demo account does not allow branding.  At least not in the same way.
The customer has pre-existing branding templates (xml) that work for manual requests.  Is there any way to access the existing branding from the API with the customers DEMO integrator key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access them through the preferences, but note that you might have to switch to the Classic UI in the DocuSign Web App.  About a year ago DocuSign re-did the UI in the Website - which is now called NDSE (New DocuSign Experience).  The previous experience is referred to as CDSE (Classic DocuSign Experience).

As of today, some but not all of the platform features have been migrated from CDSE to NDSE.  I believe Branding is one of them.  Therefore, to access the full branding features and themes try accessing the branding settings through CDSE.

To switch:

Login to your account and go to `Preferences` in top right.  Select `Switch to Classic` then select the `Branding` page to access the settings.

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I needed!
Thank you very much!